# When using unity engine I get the error ArgumentException: Input Button w is not setup. To change the input settings use: Edit -> Settings -> Input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Yeah so I am super new to unity and have pretty much zero clue what I am doing so that probably contributes to this error.

Anyways, I really don't know what to try. w is defined as alt verticle. So really Idk why this is wrong. If anyone could give me a suggestion that would be great.

Here is my code:

```
    if(Input.GetButtonDown("w")){
        transformY += 1;
    }
    if(Input.GetButtonDown("s")){
        transformY += -1;
    }

    if(Input.GetButtonDown("a")){
        transformX += 1;
    }
    if(Input.GetButtonDown("d")){
        transformX += -1;
    }

    transform.position = new Vector2(transformX, transformY);
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that the button is not setup.

> To edit, set up, or remove buttons and their names: 1. Go to Edit >
>   Project Settings > Input to bring up the Input Manager. 2. Expand Axis
>   by clicking the arrow next to it. This shows the list of the current
>   buttons you have. You can use one of these as the parameter
>   "buttonName". 3. Expand one of the items in the list to access and
>   change aspects such as the button's name and the key, joystick or
>   mouse movement that triggers it.

Source (I recommend you to read the article): https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButtonDown.html

For more info to the unity input manager:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html

Answer (score 0):

In most cases and in particular if you only have keyboard keys you can instead simply [`GetKeyDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) with a [`KeyCode`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html) like

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
{
    transformY += 1;
}
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
{
    transformY += -1;
}

if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
{
    transformX += 1;
}
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
{
    transformX += -1;
}

transform.position = new Vector2(transformX, transformY);
```